# Как динамически менять значение в переменной JS которая берет значение из input type=number

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Для подсчёта стоимости делаю калькулятор. Есть несколько input type=number из которых берутся значения которые вводит посетитель сайта. Так как значения могут менятся то и переменные в калькуляторе должны постоянно меняться

```
//Пример
let area = document.getElementById(area);
```

В примере значение из input забирается лишь один раз при загрузке страницы. А как сделать динамическое перезаписывание переменной?

Comment: Обрабатывать события. В google пишем  js input events

Comment: У меня один вопрос: сколько книжек по js вы прочитали на текущий момент?

Comment: `area.addEventListener('change', (e) => yourVariable = e.target.value)`

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/events-change - тут все события. Смотрите в сторону Событие input

Comment: А тут пример использования [события изменения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452581/1452809#1452809)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
```

```html
<input type='number' value='7' onchange='x=this.value; console.log(this.value + " x=" + x);'>
<hr>
<input type='number' value='7' oninput='y=this.value;console.log(this.value + " y=" + y);'>
```

выбирай какой вкуснее =)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const div = document.querySelector('div');

const sum = () => {
  let s = 0;
  inputs.forEach(i => s += +i.value);
  div.textContent = isNaN(s) ? 'Неверное значение' : `Сумма всех полей: ${s}`;
}
sum();

addEventListener('input', sum);
```

```html
<input type='number' value='2'>
<input type='number' value='3'>
<input type='number' value='4'>
<input type='number' value='5'>
<div></div>
```